# Put condition on select command : charindex - SQL

Tags: sql, select, if-statement

I need help with the following query. I want to put a condition on the returned value of select command which is an integer between 0 and any number.

```
DECLARE @month varchar(50);
set @month ='01-03-05-07-09-11'; <---  clarification: these are all months

Declare @cur_month int;
set @cur_month = Month(GetDate());

select charindex(str(@cur_month), @month);
```

I essentially want

```
If ( select charindex(str(@cur_month), @month))
    // successful
```

I get error

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'print'.

I tried CAST and CONVERT but to no Avail. As you can see, I am trying to see if the current month is in my @month field, I want to execute certain actions if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the answer from @PaulStock with a couple tweaks will work better.

**Changes from PaulStock's answer**

- Left pad for leading zeros.  2 != 02 and wouldn't match.
- Add hyphens at the beginning and end of the string so each value is in the form -XX-   I included this in case you realize you won't be having the leading zeros.  If you'll always have leading zeros you won't need this.

**Actual code**

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(50);
set @month ='03-05-12-09';

set @month = '-' + @month + '-'

IF CHARINDEX('-' + right('00' + CAST(MONTH('2/13/2011') AS VARCHAR), 2) + '-', @month) > 0
    PRINT 'exists'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'does not exist'
```

Comment: You probably saved me quite a lot of headache in January for point out the bug!

Comment: Jose, very true.  Good eye.  I usually have the padding expression be the total length desired in case the item being padded is empty, but in this case you better always have at least one character in the month value so only one padding character is needed.

Comment: @OCary Usually I also do the same way as you, just to be on the safe side :) but in this case only one zero is enough. Anyway, this is not very important, either way will work just fine

Comment: Thanks for improving on what I had initially. Your way is the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using string functions, use date functions since you are trying to compare one datefield to another. And use `datetime` for @month instead of varchar:

```
DECLARE @month datetime;
set @month ='09-03-05';

IF MONTH(@month) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    PRINT 'Same Month'
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated question, here is new code:

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(50);
set @month ='03-05-02-09';

IF CHARINDEX(CAST(MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR), @month) > 0
    PRINT 'Same Month'
```

Comment: plz see my clarified question. Months are only months, not a date field. This fails for september, month = 9

Comment: @Savage Garden, ah ok, I understand now.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: This won't work right in some cases.  Example: If the current month is February and December (12) is in the list, then charindex of 2 will be non-zero but February does not necessarily exist in the list.  Monthlist = '03-05-12-09' and use '2/13/2011' instead of curr_timestamp in your code to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what variation on the SQL language you are using, since SQL does not support variables and IF statements, but why not use a variable to represent the result of the condition?

```
SELECT @MyResult=charindex(str(@cur_month), @month); 

-- Now you can write an IF statement using the variable
IF @MyResult...
```

Comment: this was giving me cursor error, will try it again. I update question btw for some clarification.

Comment: Maybe, remove select and compare with an integer (for a boolean result)

Answer (score 0):

The return value for select charindex is an integer, not a boolean type. You'll need to put a boolean into your if statement.

Try something like:

If ( select charindex(str(@cur_month), @month) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

This solution pads a zero to the left for months < 10, to make sure it works for February (2) when december is on the list (12), as it was pointed out by OCary

```
DECLARE @month varchar(50);
set @month ='01-05-07-09-11-12';

If (charindex(right('0' + CAST(MONTH(getdate()) as varchar), 2), @month) > 0)
    PRINT 'Same Month'
```

if you run this:

```
select right('0' + CAST(MONTH(getdate()) as varchar), 2)
```

it returns `09`